# Saltstack: network.ip_addrs is not available

Tags: salt-stack

I've run into an issue with Saltstack version 2014.7.0, where I cannot get network information from Salt.

If I run:

```
salt-call network.ip_addrs
```

I get:

```
Function network.ip_addrs is not available
```

This only seems to happen on some of my hosts. It seems to effect the almost all of the functions in salt.modules.network, but everything else works as expected.

I suspect there's something in my environment to blame. I am running salt within a CentOS 7 docker container. I followed [these instructions](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/05/05/running-systemd-within-docker-container/) to get Systemd running under Docker, and it seems to be functioning just fine, so I don't think that's the issue, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's related. I'm using Docker as a development environment, but I will be using these formula to orchestrate virtual machines in production.

Has anyone encountered the network module not being loaded properly? Is there something that needs to be available for that module to be accessible?

I have other mechanisms to get the IP address, but none that are as easy to work with in other salt formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my problem was that I had my own custom module called "network" which was obscuring the upstream network module.

I'm pretty sure this was working at some point in the past, so I'm wondering if there might have been a change to salt in a more recent version that would cause it to conflict at a module level instead of merging methods from different modules of the same name, but I suppose it's possible that it never worked.

Comment: What version of Salt did you get this behaviour on?